# How to get the all element id's of a screen in selenium

Tags: selenium

How can I get the all element id's of a screen in selenium?

Please refer to this screenshot

[image]

Element ID is getting changed every time the page loads. I used contains@id , start-with@id, but it doesn't work every time. Now I want to get all the element id's from the webpage, so I can select the exact element.
My webpage contains input text, buttons, drop-downs.

Comment: Please add your research or code or error message so that people can help you out. [Check how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok so you get all ids on the page, then how are you then going to know what id you should be using? If you do have a way to decide which id you should be using, then **this very same way should allow you to select the elements you need without having to rely on the ids**. And *this* is what you should be doing.

Answer (score -1):

Use Xpath  instead or cssSelector. If you persist on knowing all page ids as a list of String in java,  try to execute a javascript function.

```
    // The Firefox driver supports javascript
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    // Go to the Google Suggest home page
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

     ArrayList ids = (ArrayList)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
              " var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); var allIds = []; "
              + " for (var i = 0, n = allElements.length; i < n; ++i) { "
              + " var el = allElements[i]; "
              + " if (el.id) { allIds.push(el.id); } }  return allIds; "
              );
```

Regards,
Alan Mehio
London, UK